# "No JSON object could be decoded" when batch writing items to DynamoDB table

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloud9

I am trying to write these items into a DynamoDB table. I am using the command:
"**aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://items.json**" in the Cloud9 CLI

When I run it, I receive the error: "**Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: No JSON object could be decoded**"

Up until this point, it was parsing fine, but once I got rid of all the syntax errors the error above occurs. Does anyone know what is causing this? (JSON file code below)

```
{
    "Sensors":[
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "A"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": "/Sensors/images/1.jpg"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Canada","USA","China"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "B"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "12"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["USA","China"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "C"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "medium"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "13"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "D"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "heavy"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": "/Sensors/images/2.jpg"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "14"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "E"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["USA","Russia","Haiti"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "F"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["China","Russia"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "G"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "heavy"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": "/Sensors/images/3.jpg"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N":"22"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "H"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": ""},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "45"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Jamaica","Taiwan"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "I"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "medium"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": "/Sensors/images/4.jpg"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["USA","France","Singapore"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "K"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "heavy"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["England","Wales"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "L"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": },
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Canada","Antarctica"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "M"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "ImageFile":{"S": "/Sensors/images/5.jpg"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["China","Estonia"]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "N"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "medium"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "80"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "O"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "31"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "P"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "medium"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Italy","Germany"]},
                    "Region":{"S": "Europe"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "Q"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "85"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Turkey","Bulgaria"]},
                    "Color":{"S": "Red"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "R"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "1"},
                    "Rate":{"N": "1500"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "S"},
                    "SampleRate":{"N": "21"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Ukraine","Georgia"]},
                    "Price":{"N": "36000"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "T"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "heavy"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Turkey","Phillipines"]},
                    "YearBuilt":{"N": "2003"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest":{
                
                "Item":{
                    "Sensor":{"S": "J"},
                    "SensorDescription":{"S": "light"},
                    "Locations":{"L": ["Norway","Scotland"]}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is `items.json` in the same directory as the script is being run?

Comment: yes, they are in the same place. it was running fine when I was going through the errors it was picking up, but then all of a sudden I get this error

Comment: Let me further add: The error is as I wrote in the OP, but then it is followed with "JSON received: {" Then proceeds to list the JSON file contents like shown in the OP. So it is finding the file and parsing it, but it's saying the JSON in the file is not decodable

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the posted JSON, I believe the error is b/c the JSON is malformed. Around line 193:

```json
{
    "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
            "Sensor": {
                "S": "L"
            },
            "SampleRate": {
                "N": // <--- missing value
            },
            "Locations": {
                "L": [
                    "Canada",
                    "Antarctica"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Fix up the JSON and give it a go again.